# Route Directly to the Specified page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to reach to the specific page on the very start or blank URL extension. Like if I am running the project locally So when I enter localhost:4200 then I want to reach to the **localhost:4200/pages/dashboard**

```
|-App
   |-Pages
       |-dashboard
       |-signIn
```

App Routing is like below

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/pages/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule', canActivate: [Authentication] },
  { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
  useHash: false
});
```

And Page routing is like

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PagesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        data: { breadcrumb: 'My Dashboard' },
      }
    ]
  }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

App.module is like below

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    routing,
    PagesModule,
    SignInModule,
  ],
```

Answer (score -1):

i faced same issue, i managed to make it work by changing route to this

```
PagesModule.module.ts
-----------------------
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PagesComponent,
    data: { breadcrumb: 'My Dashboard' }
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: PagesComponent,
    data: { breadcrumb: 'My Dashboard' }
  }
  }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

or try to use [wildcard routes](https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-up-wildcard-routes)

Comment: Why are we loading PagesComponent when we need the Dashboard. Also, the while route works when none of the routes matches the path